# How to detect fast moving soccer ball with OpenCV, Python, and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, detection, object-detection

This is the code. I am trying to detect different types of soccer ball using OpenCV and python. Soccer ball could of different colors. I can detect the ball if it is not moving. But, the code does not work if the ball is moving fast.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamerafrom picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time, cv2, sys, imutils, cv
import cv2.cv as cv

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (400, 300)
camera.framerate = 30
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(400, 300))

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    img   = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3)
    imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #imgg  = cv2.blur(imgg, (3,3))
                #imgg = cv2.dilate(imgg, np.ones((5, 5)))
                #imgg = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgg,(5,5),0)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgg, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=100, param2=40, minRadius=5, maxRadius=90)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", imgg)

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF    
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    if circles is None:
        continue        

    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(imgg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(imgg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.imshow("Framed", imgg)
```

Comment: have you tried using `gstreamer` ? http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-camera/streaming-video-using-gstreamer

Comment: please read this as well http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22040/take-images-in-a-short-time-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module

Comment: In the second link, it is in different format. How should I do image processing on PIL/stream image type? Please explain what is the image object in that loop?

Comment: I have not tried GStreamer. I will try using that but the question is not displaying fast video but the detection speed.